# What is the electric field in a cavity of a charged non-conductive sphere?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, gauss-law

How can we solve this problem attached below, without using the trick that considers superposition of a negative cavity and positive filled sphere.

I have started to consider to use Gauss's law, but i can't seem to figure out how to mathematically describe the integral.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of any easy way to solve this problem without using the superposition trick, and I am willing to believe that no such method exists.  Gauss's Law can generally be used to solve for the electric field in situations where you can argue from symmetry that the electric field has a constant magnitude over some easily-described surface;  this is not the case here.

The only other methods we have to find the electric field would be to integrate Coulomb's Law over the charge distribution:
$$
\vec{E}(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \iiint_V \rho \frac{ \vec{r} - \vec{r}'}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|^3} \, \mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}',
$$
or (equivalently) find the electric potential:
$$
\phi(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \iiint_V \rho \frac{ 1}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|} \, \mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}',
$$
but calculating either integral would require a tractable mathematical description of the volume $V$ that contains the charge.  If I had to guess, it might be possible to perform this integral for points $\vec{r}$ along the rotational symmetry axis of $V$;  but I would not want to try to perform this integral to find the electric field at any points off of this axis.